# How to log in to VM as same user from different machine in GCP Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I set up a VM instance on Google Compute Engine, added files to it and am able to SSH in fine from the machine I set it up on.

I am now trying to SSH to the the same VM instance as the same user from a different device, as I want access to the same files. After setting up via [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/) and SSHing in from my new device, I am not able to see those files that I added from the previous device. Command prompt shows the same username and VM instance name, but there are no files.

How do I set things up so I can SSH in from this new device and see the same data as I can see from the original device?

Comment: This is mighty strange.  Everything I know says that if you have just created ONE Compute Engine and created files in the user's home directory then those should be persistent and if you simply login again (even from a different machine) they should still be there.  Can you login simultaneously from two SSHs and validate that you are connected to the same machine in both instances.

Comment: What does `ls -l /home` show you? Do you have similar looking user name directories?

Comment: Thanks to both of you, had a look and there are two different, very similar usernames. Problem solved. Thanks again!